# Storing serialized data in an object in Neo4j

Tags: arrays, serialization, neo4j

I just migrated my Rails app from MySql to Neo4j. I have been storing a list of user's websites as a serialized string in my DB (ex. User.websites = "www.facebook.com","www.twitter.com",etc..)

When I try to create or update that attribute I get the following error:

> RuntimeError (Not allowed to store array with value...

What's the best way to go about storing an array or serialized data in Neo4j?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It highly depends on what you want to do later with this data. Are this websites meaningful peces of your data model? or are just logging stuff?

In case 1, so in case of being meaningful peces of your model. My recommendation is to have something like this User ---[related_to]---> Website(url:string)

In case 2, they can be just an array of strings inside the user node. As you can see in the [Neo4j api documentation](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j/1.5.M01/apidocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/PropertyContainer.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29), you can store as properties the next set of types:

- boolean or boolean[]
- byte or byte[]
- short or short[]
- int or int[]
- long or long[]
- float or float[]
- double or double[]
- char or char[]
- java.lang.String or String[]

  - purbon

Comment: This is Case #2. Is there anyway to easily serialize/deserialize strings to the array in Neo4j? ActiveRecord has a "serialize" method for this very same function...

Comment: not really. you can take a look if neo4j gem provide something more similar to ActiveRecord. But not sure.

Comment: Hi, I usually prefer case 1 since it gives you more flexibility. Notice you can save items as a list (has_list) if the order of the items is relevant. Neo4j.rb has support for case 2 if you want to store an array of primitive values (String, int, byte etc.) Just make sure all the items in the array are of the same type.

Comment: Check this if you want to serialize objects to primitives - http://neo4j.rubyforge.org/Neo4j/TypeConverters.html or mapping values objects - http://neo4j.rubyforge.org/Neo4j/Rails/Compositions/ClassMethods.html (just like ActiveRecord)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the discussion above, here's an example way to serialize ( http://gist.github.com/1674551 )

## neo4jhelpers.rb

```
module Neo4j
  module TypeConverters
    class SerializeConverter
      # serializes to sting
      class << self

        def convert?(type)
          type == :serialize
        end

        def to_java(value)
          return nil unless value
          JSON.generate(value).to_s
        end

        def to_ruby(value)
          return nil unless value
          JSON.parse(value.to_s)
        end
      end

    end
  end
end

Neo4j::TypeConverters.converters = nil # reload converters
```